# SCSS/SASS dynamic background image based on class name

Tags: css, sass

I was looking for a "sassy" way to do something like this:

```css
.btn-save {
  background: image-url('save.svg');
}

.btn-load {
  background: image-url('load.svg');
}

.btn-back {
  background: image-url('back.svg');
}
```

Is there a way I could grab the last part of the class name and pass it to a function to load the appropriate SVG icon? I was thinking it'd look something like:

```css
@function load-svg($svg-name) {
  background: image-url($svg-name + ".svg");
}

.btn-* {
  // I'm not sure how to get the $svg-name here
  load-svg($svg-name);
}
```

But I wasn't sure if that's possible to do in SCSS. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **Dynamic** no....that's not the way CSS/SCSS works. You can write a mixin for it but that's not what your asking...right?

Comment: Anything to help me not having to define all the different styles for the buttons. I looked into mixin but I don't think I can achieve what I want with it. But if you can see a way to achieve this with a mixin (or any other ways), can you post it as an answer and I'll take a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a DRY approach you could pass a list to a mixin

```
@mixin setSVGButton($svgs) {
  @each $svg in $svgs {
    .btn-#{$svg} {
      background-image: url(#{$svg}.svg);
    }
  } 
}


@include setSVGButton(('save', 'load', 'back'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this

```
@mixin btn($btn-type) {
    .btn-#{$btn-type} {
        background: image-url('#{$btn-type}.svg');
  }
}

@include btn('save');
@include btn('load');
@include btn('back');
```

Comment: Ah that looks like it could work, but is there another way to do it so that I won't have to include each of the button type? I'm just looking for the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)-est way to achieve this.